# Schengen Visa - financial documents

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

I currently reside in the UK as an international student and I am planning to take a trip to Europe, and therefore I am applying for Schengen Visa.

In the last 3-4 months, for my daily expenses I used my foreign debit card and my UK bank account have a few weeks with 0 pound balance and no transactions, however I have recently paid substantial money for tuition and started to use it more frequently. If I put enough money on my UK bank account ( more than minimum requirement by the visa centre), will this be enough to provide evidence for the proof of finance? Since my UK bank account was rarely used, I wonder if visa centre would question my financial sufficiency.

As an alternative, I can request online bank reference and statements from my bank account back at home, but I wonder if visa centre accept financial documents which were not issued at the branch by the manager.

Thank you.

Comment: `however I have recently paid substantial money for tuition and started to use it more frequently` Funds parking, check this site there are multiple questions on this.

Comment: You should proof your finances, not your UK account. Just give the details of your home country bank account. This makes also more strength to your connection to your home country. I do not understand your last sentence. Could you have some official bank statements from your bank? Why do you need the bank manager?

Answer (score 1):

A sudden influx of money into an account you have not otherwise used will not help at all -- it will not tell the consular officer anything reliable about your economic circumstances.

Your best bet is to document the history of *both* accounts as well as you're able to. If the only account statements you can get from your home account are online statements you print yourself, that's not ideal but certainly much better than nothing. Be aware that you may need to enclose certified translations; check with the particular consulate you're applying to what they require.